# Move saved game Witcher 3 from Switch to Xbox Series

Tags: pc, the-witcher-3, nintendo-switch, xbox-series-x-series-s

I have the Witcher game on Switch, (and for those who are wondering: it is worth it.. if you don't have another console to play it on).

Now, I have an Xbox Series S and want to play on it. I know I can transfer my saves from Switch to PC on either Steam or GOG. But, I didn't find any information regarding whether or not I can transfer from PC to Xbox Series (obv not possible to do Switch to XboxS).
I want to be sure it is possible before buying the game again on Xbox Series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The save transfer functionality is only between Switch and PC.

The functionality is not available on Xbox or PS. And it's not currently looking like it will come at all. https://www.vg247.com/witcher-3-cross-save-option-isnt-coming-ps4-xbox-one

So what you want to do is, sadly, impossible.